# Как сделать, чтобы Chrome открывался в режиме инкогнито по умолчанию везде, а не только с ярлыка?

Tags: google-chrome, windows, браузер

Везде только о том, как сделать режим инкогнито с ярлыка (добавить параметр --incognito в свойствах ярлыка). А как сделать, чтобы, например, при открытии локальных файлов html из проводника Windows или когда другое приложение что-то открывает в браузере, браузер открывался в режиме инкогнито?

Comment: Посмотри ассоциацию html файлов в панели управления и переназначь на ярлык курлык.

Comment: Разобрался. Можно в HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command поменять значение на "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito  -- "%1"